# Javascript bridge / upcall to JavaFX (via JSObject.setMember() method) breaks when moving class into a package

Tags: javafx, webview, jsobject

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661051/javascript-bridge-upcall-to-javafx-via-jsobject-setmember-method-breaks-wh) question, but I believe we are encountering different issues.

**Setup:**

I have a Kotlin class that interfaces with a TinyMCE instance running in a JavaFX Webview. I am setting up upcalls from Javascript to JavaFX as shown below, in the `TinyMCEInterface` class:

```kotlin
inner class BridgeObject {
    fun setEditorAndSelection(ed : JSObject?) {
        editorObj = ed
        selectionObj = editorObj?.getMember("selection") as JSObject?
    }

    fun setInterfaceContent(newContent : String) {
        contentProp.value = newContent
    }
}

// after WebEngine loads successfully
val bridgeObj : BridgeObject = BridgeObject()
(webEngine.executeScript("window") as JSObject).setMember("bridgeObj", bridgeObj)
```

I am then calling these methods from Javascript, in TinyMCE setup:

```js
ed.on('init', function() {
    ed.setContent(initContent)
    window.bridgeObj.setEditorAndSelection(ed)
    window.bridgeObj.setInterfaceContent(ed.getContent())
});

ed.on('Change SelectionChange', function(e) {
    window.bridgeObj.setInterfaceContent(ed.getContent())
});
```

**Problem:**

This works perfectly fine when the `TinyMCEInterface` class file lies in the root directory of my application (in package `com.myself.app`). That is, when the file structure looks like this:

```
com.myself.app/
│
├─ TinyMCEInterface.kt
│
├─ Main.kt
```

But breaks when I move `TinyMCEInterface` into a package (in package `com.myself.app.somepackage`):

```
com.myself.app/
│
├─ somepackage/
│  ├─ TinyMCEInterface.kt
│
├─ Main.kt
```

When I say "breaks", there are no errors; the calls to member functions of `window.bridgeObj` simply do not happen and quietly fail. I am completely bewildered as to how this can be happening.

Thanks in advance for any advice!